# Python : Solving this cyclic import conundrum

Tags: python, python-import

I am running into an import conundrum. After adding a new import I am getting the following error

```
from studentApp.models import modelStudent
  File abc, line 6, in <module>
    from interviewApp.models import modelInterviewQuestion
  File "xyz", line 4, in <module>
    from mainApp.models import modelPatient
ImportError: cannot import name modelPatient
```

Now this is what my file looks like
mainApp/models.py

```
from studentApp.models import modelStudent #<---Added this and I get the error
```

and this is in my
studentApp/models.py file

```
from interviewApp.models import modelInterviewQuestion #---> has a call to modelPatient inside
from mainApp.models import modelPatient 
from labApp.models import modelLabTestName #---> has a call to modelPatient inside
```

Now in my interviewApp/models.py I have this which is causing a cyclic import

```
from mainApp.models import modelPatient #<---This is what is initiated the call
```

I understand why this is happening but I am not sure how to fix this problem.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: The best solution is to reorganize your modules to break the circular references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circular dependency is that `studentApp/models.py` imports `mainApp.models` and `mainApp/models.py` imports `studentApp.models`. One solution is to move `modelPatient` into it's own module and then import it into `mainApp/models.py` and `studentApp/models.py`.

Comment: Thanks that did help however looks like i really need to refactor