# ImportError: cannot import name 'variable' from 'module'

Tags: python

I am using Flask for my web framework. I am having an issue with imports. I am not understanding why can't I import my variable when I declare it within my `my_app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from my_app.some_module.my_class.py import auth


app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()

class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

config = Config()
```

My conflictuous imports are present in `my_app/some_module/my_class.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from my_app import login_manager  # this one works fine
from my_app import config

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)
```

I run the app with `run.py`:

```
from my_app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

I then get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ".../my_app/some_module/my_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_app import login_manager, config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'my_app' (.../my_app/__init__.py)
```

Project structure is:

```
my_app
  + __init__.py
  some_module
    + __init__.py
    + my_class.py
+ run.py
```

Comment: maybe you meant to import the class `Config` instead of the variable `config` (note the capitalisation / lack of it)?

Comment: No I really want the variable

Comment: ok, just making sure

Comment: Is that *all* the contents of your `__init__.py`?

Comment: Show us the complete, exact error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: What part of your code imports ``my_module.my_class``?

Comment: For the record, I just gave it a quick test with your example code and it worked for me with using `import my_module.my_class` from a higher directory.

Comment: `from . import config` ?

Comment: I am sorry guys. I improved my question

Comment: Does it still not work without `login_manager`? I don't really have any ideas but I would be interested to see what the solution ends up as.

Comment: I just added `login_manager` as an example to prove that I can actually import that variable with no problem

Comment: It seems to me that it makes more sense to import the class `Config` rather than the variable `config`, and declare a new Config object in the `my_class.py`. Is there a reason to do it the way you have?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue at all. How do you run this? What is in the rest of the traceback? The line ``File ".../my_app/some_module/my_class.py"`` indicates that you are running this from a subfolder of ``my_app``, correct?

Comment: @G.Anderson I could do that indeed. But I would still like to understand why can't I import my variable

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I updated the question with how I run my app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : Solving this cyclic import conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927416/python-solving-this-cyclic-import-conundrum)

Answer (score 3):

You have a cyclic import: `my_app.some_module` -> `my_app.some_module.my_class` -> `my_app.some_module`.

You can fix this by moving both `Config` and `config` to a separate module `my_app.some_module.config`.

```
# my_app.some_module.my_config
class Config:
    pass

config = Config()

# my_app.some_module.my_class
from .my_config import config

# my_app.some_module.__init__
from .my_config import config
from .my_class import MyClass
```

This means that every import does not depend on previous imports:

```
my_app.some_module
|-> my_app.some_module.my_class -> my_app.some_module.config
\-> my_app.some_module.my_config
```

Doing imports this way instead of moving the import for `.my_class` to the end of `__init__.py` is more robust. You can freely reorder the imports of `.my_class` and `.my_config` at the top of files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a cyclic dependency. By the time you import `auth` from `my_app.some_module.my_class.py` your `config` is not set yet. Try moving that import to the end of the `my_app/__init__.py` file like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager


app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()

class Config:
    pass

config = Config()

from my_app.some_module.my_class.py import auth
```